# Different behaviour on similar flagging popups

Tags: bug, chat

I noticed that in this [page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/admin/flagged) the popups displayed when clicking on the triangle next to the flagged comment is allowed to have multiple instances. This behaviour is different from the component found in [any chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases), in which if you click twice on the triangle the previous popup gets removed and replaced by the newer one. I guess the latter is the expected functionality.

This are examples of the page with multiple identical popup instances:

**Before clicking:**

[image: Before clicking]

**After one click:**

[image: After one click]

**After many clicks:**

[image: After many clicks]

Comment: Ah, memories of Windows 98 error dialogs. I can almost hear the "THUNK" error sound.